# Quicksort is not sorting correctly

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort

I essentially copied my code from a UCBerkeley quicksort video, but it only seems to sort in pairs almost. I'm not sure what's going on here.

I've looked through each line multiple times and can't see what's wrong. Everything makes sense to me.

```
static <E extends Comparable<? super E>>
void quicksort(E[] A, int low, int high) {
    if (low < high) {
        int pivotIndex = (low + high) / 2;
        E pivot = A[pivotIndex];
        // move pivot to end
        A[pivotIndex] = A[high];
        A[high] = pivot;

        int i = low - 1;
        int j = high;
        do {
            do {
                i++;
            } while (A[i].compareTo(pivot) < 0);
            do {
                j--;
            } while ((A[i].compareTo(pivot)) > 0 && (j > low));
            if (i < j) {
                E swap = A[i];
                A[i] = A[j];
                A[j] = swap;
            }
        } while (i < j);
        // i is now the first spot in the right partition (where we will put pivot)
        // now put pivot back where it belongs
        A[high] = A[i];
        A[i] = pivot;
        quicksort(A, low, i - 1); // sort left partition
        quicksort(A, i + 1, high);
    }
}
```

I expected[2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 101, 200, 300] but got [3, 5, 2, 6, 10, 101, 200, 300]

Answer (score 1):

The compare in the second inner loop is using A[i] for the compare, when it should be using A[j]:

```
            } while ((A[j].compareTo(pivot)) > 0 && (j > low));  // A[j] not A[i]
```

---

An alternative variation for this type of quicksort doesn't swap the pivot with A[high], and by leaving the pivot in the middle, the code won't need to check for j > low in the second inner loop, which is a bit faster. Using this variation needs other changes: init j to high + 1, and the two recursive calls should be quicksort(A, low, j) and quicksort(A, j+1, high). Note that values equal to the pivot, including the pivot itself, may end up in either either partition, since values equal to pivot get swapped.

Example code for primitives (int), that uses recursion on smaller or equal part, then iterates back for larger part to avoid stack overflow in worst case scenario. It can be converted to use generic object E.

```
    public static void qsort(int[] a, int lo, int hi)
    {
        while(lo < hi){
            int  md = lo+(hi-lo)/2;
            int  ll = lo-1;
            int  hh = hi+1;
            int p = a[md];
            int t;
            while(true){
                while(a[++ll] < p);
                while(a[--hh] > p);
                if(ll >= hh)
                    break;
                t     = a[ll];
                a[ll] = a[hh];
                a[hh] = t;
            }
            ll = hh++;
            if((ll - lo) <= (hi - hh)){
                qsort(a, lo, ll);
                lo = hh;
            } else {
                qsort(a, hh, hi);
                hi = ll;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Your way makes sense, too, but do you know specifically why my code doesn't work? It makes just as much sense to me.

Comment: @ellesummer - the problem wasn't the swapping of the pivot to A[high], it was the second inner loop using A[i] for the compare when it should be using A[j] for the compare. I updated my answer. I don't know if there are other issues, since finding quicksort failure cases can be difficult, if there's just some subtle issue with a specific implementation.

Comment: Thank you soo much. I completely didn't notice that.